# Use Groovy AST transformations to modify Java classes

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have developed some Groovy AST transformations and I'd like to use them to modify Java classes. When I compile annotated Java class with groovyc it works, for example:

> groovyc -classpath 'path-to-lib-with-transformations'
>   AnnotatedClass.java

produces properly compiled *.class* files with applied transformations, but when I try to compile AnnotatedClass.java using Gradle with Groovy plugin (I put this class into **src/main/groovy**) it doesn't work. It seems that class compiled via javac, despite it locates in **src/main/groovy**

Comment: Tried renaming `AnnotatedClass.java` to `AnnotatedClass.groovy`?

Comment: @tim_yates, it works of course, but the point is to modify java classes

Comment: You can't. Javac won't do groovy ast transformations

Comment: @tim_yates, so I want to compile .java files not using javac but groovyc

Comment: Rename them to `.groovy` that's what that does